# How to call a script with SignalR when item created to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, signalr

I'm newbie with SignalR and want to learn so much. i already read beginner documents. But in this case i've stucked. what i want to do is when a user got new message i want to fire a script, like alert or showing div like "you have new mail" for notify the recieved user.  And my question is how can i do that ? is there anyone know how to achieve this ? or good "step-by-step" document? i really want to work with SignalR.

ps: i'm using Visual Studio 2012 and MsSQL server

edit: i forgot to write, notification must be fired when message created to DB

Thank you

Comment: Actually, there are several questions. First, how do you detect a change in the DB? Polling SQL? Broker? Only then, you will be able to ask the second question, which is how to notify the user when the change is detected.

Comment: i don't know what is the best way to do is. And i'm open for suggestions. SqlDependency is good for this ? (if i have many users this would be a good for performance?)

Comment: You can have SignalR scripts ping every 1000ms or something reasonable, and send up the UserId. In your server side code check the UserIds messages, and if it has any, have the server then call a script to display the you have mail message. Simple.

Comment: If this has solved your issue please accept the answer I provided, other wise if you have questions please fire away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Scripts use the following, naturally this is not all the code, but enough based off tutorials to get you going. Your userId will be generated server side, and somehow your script can get it off an element of the page, or whatever method you want. It runs when the connection is started and then every 10 seconds. Pinging our server side method of **CheckMessage()** .

This js would need refactoring but should give you the general idea.

```
...
var messageHub = $.connection.messageHub;
var userId = 4;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
         StartCheck();
}

//Runs every 10 seconds..
function StartCheck()
{
    setInterval(messageHub.server.checkMessage(userId,$.connection.hub.id), 10000);
}
```

This method takes in a userId, assuming your db is set up that way, and grabs them all from your database; naturally the method used is probably not appropriate for your system, however change it as you need to. It also checks if the user has any messages, and if so sends down another message to our SignalR scripts.

```
public void CheckMessage(int userId,int connectionId)
{

    var user = userRepo.RetrieveAllUsers.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.id == userId);

    if(user.HasMessages)
    {

     Clients.Group(connectionId).DisplayMailPopUp();
    }

}
```

Finally this message, upon being called would run your code to do the 'You have Mail alert' - be it a popup, a div being faded in or whatever.

```
...
messageHub.client.displayMailPopUp = function () {
  alert("You have Mail!");
};
...
```

Hopefully this helps - I recommend the following links for reading up and building your first SignalR app:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5
And a smaller sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SignalR-Getting-Started-b9d18aa9